# Step wise AIC in model selection in R

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

When I was trying to do the model selection using the function `step` or `stepAIC` in `R`, there is an argument `direction` in these functions. And when I specifying `backward`, `forward` or `both` in `direction`, usually I got different best models (i.e. lowest AIC). I was wondering why the direction matters? And usually which direction is better to use?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The direction changes the algorithms:

- backward: your model will be built from your base model by adding predicting variables
- forward: it's the exact opposite. You remove variables from your model iteratively
- both: trying to remove variables & adding new ones.

Thus, the results can happen to be very different

By adding `trace=TRUE` when calling the function, you can see what is actually atempted by the function: which variables will be removed, which are added.